# Python Conditionals and If Statements Syntax

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax, conditional-statements

I am having trouble with my syntax around if statements and conditionals. I am trying to write a function which returns what time to set an alarm clock to depending on two parameters, what day it is and whether the person is on vacation or not. My days are encoded as 0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday ... 6 = Saturday. The function needs to return `'7:00`for weekdays while not on vacation, `'10:00'` during weekdays on vacation and weekends while not on vacation, and finally return `'off'` on weekends not on vacation. So far I have the following code but I am getting a syntax error in Wing and can not figure out what my issue is. Any help is appreciated.

```
def alarm_clock(day, on_vacation):
   """Alarm clock function"""

   if (int(day) < 6 and int(day) != 0) and not on_vacation:
       return('7:00')

   elif (int(day) = 6 or int(day) = 0) and not on_vacation:
       return('10:00')

   elif (int(day) < 6 or int(day) != 0) and on_vacation:
       return('10:00')

   elif (int(day) = 6 or int(day) = 0) and on_vacation:
       return('off')
```

Comment: The equality operator is `==`, not `=`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare values using `=` (assignment operator). You should use `==` instead.

Example: current: `int(day) = 6`, correct: `int(day) == 6`

Answer (score 0):

That's because your are using `=` instead of `==` for comparisons.

Like in `int(day) = 6`. It should be:

```
int(day) == 6
```

Comment: Oh wow, thanks so much!